# Duplicate after every row and column in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array:

```
first = array([[4, 5],
               [7, 9]])
```

And I would like to duplicate every element `i` into every following `i + 1` row and `i + 1` column.

My output should look like this:

```
array([[4, 4, 5, 5],
       [4, 4, 5, 5],
       [7, 7, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 9, 9]])
```

Comment: I can't think of any clever way without doing it element by element, taking `first[0,0} * np.ones((2,2))` and concatenating the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just repeat twice:

```
>>> first.repeat(2, axis=1).repeat(2, axis=0)
array([[4, 4, 5, 5],
       [4, 4, 5, 5],
       [7, 7, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 9, 9]])
```

*Slightly* more compact:

```
first.repeat(2,1).repeat(2,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.zoom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html) with the `order` set to `0` to keep replicating your array

```
>>> arr
array([[4, 5],
       [7, 9]])
>>> scipy.ndimage.zoom(arr, 2, order=0)
array([[4, 4, 5, 5],
       [4, 4, 5, 5],
       [7, 7, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 9, 9]])
```

`zoom` also works with greater values and/or can approximate to floats (zooming in or out) and in different scales by-axis (including higher dimensions)

```py
>>> scipy.ndimage.zoom(arr, 5, order=0)
array([[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
>>> scipy.ndimage.zoom(arr, 0.5, order=0)
array([[4]])
>>> scipy.ndimage.zoom(arr, (2,3), order=0)
array([[4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],
       [7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9]])
```